# cs50 finance, 404 not found error upon loading into server and 500 internal server error for register

Tags: finance, cs50, internal-server-error

Whenever I first load into the website after running flask, I get the '404 not found' error and I am not sure how to change it to just show the login page.

And when I try to register a new user, the information does get recorded and hashed in the database but I receive a 500 internal server error where I can only access the homepage if I used the login page. I am not sure how I should go about fixing this so would greatly appreciate any help on this.

application.py(login)

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                          username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to portfolio page
        return redirect("/portfolio")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

application.py (register)

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Ensure confirm password is submitted        
        elif not request.form.get("confirm-password"):
            return apology("must confirm password", 403)

        # if confirm password does not match password
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm-password"):
            return apology("must match new password", 403)

        # update database for username and hash new password
        rows = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)", 
        username=request.form.get("username"), hash=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))

        # Give user id number
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to portfolio page
        return redirect("/portfolio")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

for register.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" 
            placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" 
            type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out for the register section.

I took out this line

```
# update database for username and hash new password
        rows = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)", 
        username=request.form.get("username"), hash=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
```

I decided to rename my 'confirm-password' to 'confirm_password' just to maintain some level of similarity in the code.
But more importantly, it worked when I used these lines of code instead:

```
 # if confirm password does not match password
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm_password"):
            return apology("password does not match")

        # Hash password / Store password hash_password =
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        # Add user to database
        result = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)",
                username = request.form.get("username"),
                hash = hashed_password)

        if not result:
            return apology("The username is already taken")

        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                  username = request.form.get("username"))
```

I also recently found that if I did this cause I wanted to keep index(portfolio link) separated from /(homepage link):

```
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

before the @app.route(/index) section

In addition, I added onto line 29 in layout.html

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="blue">C</span><span class="red">$</span><span class="yellow">5</span><span class="green">0</span> <span class="red">Finance</span></a>
```

these additional lines before and after it. So that it would not take me to the login page when I have already logged in after clicking on the home button:

```
            {% if session.user_id %}
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/portfolio"><span class="blue">C</span><span class="red">$</span><span class="yellow">5</span><span class="green">0</span> <span class="red">Finance</span></a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="blue">C</span><span class="red">$</span><span class="yellow">5</span><span class="green">0</span> <span class="red">Finance</span></a>
            {% endif %}
```

I stopped having the 404 not found error